# Backbone faceted filter

Tags: backbone.js, faceted-search

I'm trying to find facet filtering solution for backbone (collection data). I didn't mean searchbox, but something like here http://www.documentcloud.org/public/search/ - project list in left sidebar.
Is there some library for this stuff?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you found already?

Comment: Nothing except https://github.com/rmdort/backbone-faceted-search - which isn't library.

Answer (score 0):

At my company we are developing this, maybe it might interest you:
https://github.com/arillo/Backbone.Facetr

Comment: Welcome! You should paste the interesting part here, in case the link is not avaiable any longer.